# How to know if I am using Java EE?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, bash

Today I installed Java EE by downloading the `.sh` file from the [official Oracle source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html) and running it using the `sudo sh filename.sh` command.

However, I have several versions of Java in my Linux Mint machine, which I access when using the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java`:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1074      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1074      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

And when I use the `java -version` command, this is what I get:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

By reading all these outputs, I never find anything mentioning any "Java EE" version. So I have some questions I need clarification with:

1. How do I really know if I am using it as a default?
2. If I am not using it by default, how can I do it?
3. If the above steps are not possible, how do I just set my Eclipse IDE to use it?

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Comment: Duplicate question on superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/681828/how-to-know-if-i-am-using-java-ee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java EE is not a replacement for Java SE, it's a set of APIs and services ***on top*** of Java SE.  Or [in Oracle's own words:](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/java-ee001.htm#GCRKK)

> The Java EE platform is built on top of the Java SE platform. The Java EE platform p rovides an API and runtime environment for developing and running large-scale, multi-tiered, scalable, reliable, and secure network applications.

What you downloaded here is an Oracle Glassfish server (the reference implementation of Java EE - its own site can be found [here](https://glassfish.java.net/)) with a bundled JDK (which you won't need because you already had Java SE installed).  Doesn't look *that* fresh to me with its bundled jdk7u10...

Java EE is quite comprehensive and big, the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) is a very impressive book with 1010 pages.